# get the page title in which iframe is loaded

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, web-applications

I have three web pages in my application in which one web page is used as an iframe in other two web pages. how can i get the page title of the normal web page in the iframe webpage

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to get it with `parent.document.title` in javascript